# react-native run-android, can not running on my phone

Tags: react-native

My react-native project running ios, but can't run my android phone. This is error code ;

Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/haktan/Desktop/arsiv/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build.gradle' line: 21
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-linear-gradient'.

  > Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUİLD FAILED

Total time: 55.675 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I can't install react-native-linear-gradient. Error code;

Haktan-MacBook-Pro:arsiv haktan$ npm install react-native-linear-gradient --save
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.5.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN native-base@2.8.1 requires a peer of react@>=16.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN native-base@2.8.1 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.56.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

- react-native-linear-gradient@2.5.3
  updated 1 package and audited 29046 packages in 34.783s
  found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Check this subject please. I added the error code.

Comment: How did you get react-native-linear-gradient in the first place if you cannot install it? Are you trying to use a linear gradient package? If so, it would be helpful to know how you installed it/what you installed.

Comment: Are you using the `react-native-linear-gradient` package? If so, have you linked it as well?

Comment: This is already installed. I tried install but returned error code. You can check this error code in subject.